# Что делать если нужно отослать запрос противоречащий принципеам REST API?

Tags: php, rest

REST API следует правилам что, если надо считать данные - исопльзуем GET, если создать - POST.

Сейчас у меня классическое приложение без REST API. Необходимо переделать. И на данный момент у меня есть такая ситуация, что в некоторых местах для получения одних данных, нужно отослать другие и эти другие данные гораздо больше по размеру, нежели можно отдать в GET. Поэтому я осознанно передаю их через POST.

При переходе на REST - как быть? Даже готовые решения, например для того же *Yii2* основываются на принципе GET - получение, POST - создание  (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-quick-start ,   https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-routing)

Comment: а где описано, что получение данных через get это обязательный атрибут REST ?

Comment: никто не знает точно что такое REST и никаких правил нет, пишете как считаете нужным

Comment: REST - это всего лишь рекомендации по тому, как организовывать ваш API, не более, как вам уже написали.

Comment: @teran просто везде эти правила написаны, в т.ч. в ссылках по yii которые я указал, и во всех видео говорят. Поэтому я и сделал вывод. Просто почему тогда бы не указать, что это рекомендуется, а не строго к исполнению? Если можно отступать от правил - хорошо))

Comment: @teran или я неправильно понял? ведь нельзя же отправить данные через POST  и при этом в REST принять данныей методом GET.

Comment: я по вашим ссылками что-то такого особо не увидел ничего. поэтому и спросил. С гетом все просто, пока у нас есть пара параметров или их нет вовсе. Как только начинают появляется более структурированные параметры запроса, то их пакуют в json и шлют постом в теле, вот и все дела.

Comment: @teran понял. спасибо.

Comment: можете привести пример данных, которые вы передаёте в ПОСТ, но они не вмещаются в ГЕТ?

Comment: @ArchDemon Ну там большой массив объектов. Объекты типа `{pointId: 1, type: 'ms', .... и т.д.}`  на основе этого массива строится некая большая структура  с различными зависимостями и присылается на клиент для отображения

Comment: строится некая большая структура где: в памяти или в БД?

Comment: @ArchDemon на стороне сервера. Тут несколько ситуаций бывает. Бывает, что на стороне сервера на основе данных строится другой набор данных, совсем другой по структуре, типу и визуальному представлению (условно говоря по набору хим элементов и паре параметров строится возможное представление галактики с позиционированием, гравитационным воздействием планет). Иногда это просто конвертация из одного типа данных в другой (калькуляционные вычисления), иногда, в другом случае, дополняются данными из БД.

Comment: Я вас не об этом спросил, а о том, сохраняете ли вы данные в БД, т.е. меняете ли каким-либо образом состояние сервера

Comment: @ArchDemon нет. иначе бы я использовал бы POST, по логике, которую я описал в самом вопросе